# i want to fix one error for configure the iomad using wamp server

Tags: php, wamp

I'm getting the following error

> Fatal error: During inheritance of Iterator: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function default_error_handler(), 4 passed in C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\filestorage\zip_archive.php on line 37 and exactly 5 expected in C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\setuplib.php:425 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\filestorage\zip_archive.php(37): default_error_handler(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\wamp64\www\i...', 512) #1 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\filestorage\zip_packer.php(28): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #2 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\filelib.php(55): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #3 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\formslib.php(46): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #4 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\local\email\local_lib.php(25): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #5 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\local\email\lib\api.php(24): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #6 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\local\email\lib.php(26): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #7 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\local\iomad\lib\user.php(30): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #8 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\local\iomad\lib\company.php(28): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #9 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\local\iomad\lib\iomad.php(25): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #10 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\navigationlib.php(34): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #11 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\setup.php(604): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #12 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\config.php(1073): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #13 C:\wamp64\www\iomad\index.php(30): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\i...') #14 {main} in C:\wamp64\www\iomad\lib\filestorage\zip_archive.php on line 37

I am expecting to resolve this error

Comment: please anyone know this answer

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example (including the `default_error_handler` function you called)

Comment: Your question is missing any detail at all of the code, so it's impossible to tell you what to fix. But based purely on the error message, it appears to be the same problem as in the linked question. In which case one of the key pieces of information you forgot to tell us is that either you've just upgraded to a new PHP version, or you're using a library that was designed for use with an old PHP version.

Comment: If you do have other questions in future, rather than adding comments just repeating that you need help, think about *how you can help others to help you*. What information do you know that someone reading the question doesn't, that seems likely to be relevant? What examples can you provide that others can use to reproduce or understand the problem, and point you to a specific solution?